How to specify that a kernel hyperarameter is always fixed in scikit-learn GP kernels?
I am trying to implement the following simple custom GP kernel in scikit-learn:
class uniform(Kernel):
    def __init__(self, M):
        # Initialize the parameters of your custom kernel
        self.M = M
        # Call the superclass constructor
        super().__init__()
        
    @property
    def hyperparameter_M(self):
        return Hyperparameter("M", "numeric", "fixed")
    
    def __call__(self, X, Y=None, eval_gradient=False):
        # The gradient of the kernel k(X, X) with respect to the log of the
        # hyperparameter of the kernel. Only returned when `eval_gradient`
        # is True.

        if Y is None:
            Y = X
        X = np.atleast_2d(X)
        Y = np.atleast_2d(Y)
        D = np.shape(X)[1]
        covariance_matrix = 1
        w = np.arange(1,self.M+1,1)
        for d in range(D):
            a = feature(X[:,d],self.M).eval()
            b = feature(Y[:,d],self.M).eval()
            covariance_matrix_d = np.inner(a, b)
            covariance_matrix *= covariance_matrix_d

        if eval_gradient:
            # grad_matrix = np.zeros(covariance_matrix.shape)
            return covariance_matrix, None
        else:
            return covariance_matrix

    def diag(self, X):
        return np.diag(self.__call__(X, Y=X, eval_gradient=False))
    
    def is_stationary(self):
        return True

The issue is that when fitting a GP with this kernel, the gradient is required, although there are no hyperaparameters that are non fixed (uniform.theta is an empty list). Returning None as in the shared code is not the solution. Am I doing something wrong?

Take a look at the code I've edited in the answer. Hopefully it solves your issue.
